# In react 18 how to I use createRoot to render a class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-18

I'm trying to convert my app to React 18's render method.

I have a class component that doesn't render to `root` element. How do I get the createRoot element to render the component and where do I put

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("myrenderelement")); 
// please notice I'm not rendering to root as I said above   ^^^
```

This goes outside the class definition, in the state... where ?
If I put it outside the class I get this error:

```
Syntax error: Unexpected token (80:6)

  78 |  
  79 |
> 80 |  root.render() {
     |      ^
  81 |      return (
  82 |          <div className="myclass">
  83 |              <div className="container">
```

Same for

```
root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("myrenderelement"));
root.render() {
```

and to

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("myrenderelement")).render() {
```

I always says "Unexpected token" on that line

If I try to:

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            <my state vars>
            root: ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("myrenderelement"))
        }
    }
    ....
```

then

```
this.state.root.render() { <whatever>
```

I get unexpected token again on render line :/

How do I render the class component ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter to `root.render` whether your component is a `class` component or a function component. In either case, you pass the React element to render to it (usually creating the element via JSX), as shown by [the page the dev version of React v18 links to](https://reactjs.org/link/switch-to-createroot) if you use the old way:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```js
class Child extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>Child Component</div>;
    }
}

class Example extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Top-Level Component
                <Child />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

You only use this for the root of your application, the top-level. Not in elements rendered by that top-level element.

Comment: What I was doing wrong is that I was substituting the render method in inner components as well and not only in the root. As soon as I removed the code from there it worked. Thanks. :)